# Javascript jQuery hide fields when opening page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    $('#advert').live('change', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(":text").show();
        } else {
            $(":text").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

This code shows and hides text fields when the checkbox is checked. It works perfectly but I want the text field to be hidden when the page opens.

Comment: multiple ways.. add text { display: none} css. or hide it when the document loads.     $(function(){
         $(':text').hide();
    });

Comment: You can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) and pass in the condition - `$(':text').toggle(this.checked)` to shorten your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#advert').live('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(":text").show();
    } else {
    $(":text").hide();
    }
    }).trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

This will also handle the case when the user clicks the box, goes to another page, clicks the back button, and has the box checked by the browser automatically.

Comment: As a note, you shouldn't use .live() as it has been deprecated in 1.7+ and completely removed from 1.9.  Use .on() instead!

Answer (score 5):

Hide the text fields on document ready.
The document ready event, says "When I'm finished loading, execute this code".  So on page load it fires .hide() on your text fields.  It's very powerful!

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $(":text").hide();
});
```

Another approach is to set the style to "display: none;" on each of these.  Then they start out hidden

Comment: Click the box, then go to another site like google.com, then click the back button. Broken.

Comment: This is true.  Joe's answer is very robust.  The .trigger() event he chains onto the $("#advert") causes the event to fire when the page is loaded.  This let's you determine the state of the check boxes and set the visibility of the text fields accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

give your text fields a class of maybe .text
and then use css like so:

`.text{
display: none;
}`

or jquery like so:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $(":text").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Exchange

```
.show();
```

and

```
.hide();
```

Comment: Use @Danwilliger's solution!